# Update Table row on Particular date which is stored in another table

Tags: post

The problem I am facing is, I am having a table in which I have Cheque Amount And Cheque Date Field. So, Sometimes I might have **post** dated Cheque, may be of after 3-4 days.. So in this case, on particular date Cheque amount should add to related bank amount. Here I need some help.

Comment: what have you got so far? what programming language are you using? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Paste some data and table structure

Comment: Thanks for Quick response. I am using .Net 2010 as a programming language and SQL 2008 R2 as a back end. I am creating small account application, in that I need to manage bank account and Current cash transactions. My need is, Whenever I am doing entry of Post dated check transaction, the check amount should added or deducted from the bank account on check date. i.e. Today, In Transaction Table I am inserting row for 10000Rs check of ABC bank having check date:25/10/2012. so this 10000 should be added to ABC bank (Bank table)on date, 25/10/2012

Comment: Purchase_Id PayableAmount   ChequeDate  Bank_Id  PurchaseDate
----------- -------------   ----------  -------  -------------
382         266774.00       2012-10-15  1        2012-10-01       
387         211808.00       2012-10-20  1        2012-10-09 
Bank_Id     BankName  CurrentBalance
----------- ----------
1           Axis Bank 4287390.50